# create a new row in google spreadsheet from an html form

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script

I am medical researcher, and I am creating a database of my patients, I have a form in html and want the variables obtained were stored in a spreadsheet of google, so far I have only this:
spreadsheet:
[my spreadsheet in google](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KYR7SefLy5P-JP3LqdKsRRd_bkwTHFGFQQ0rnD3JfUM/edit?usp=sharing)

code.gs:

```
function addProduct() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(['name', 'age']);
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index.html')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Name and age!
    <input type=text name=name id=name>
    <input type=number name=age id=age>
    <input type=submit onclick=google.script.run.addProduct()>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know how to link the variables in the html form, to the code.gs to enter the answers in a new row with the `sheet.appendRow`
I will appreciate your help,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your input tags are not in a form, so you can't get the form element as a whole.  Which you don't need to do, but it's worth mentioning because there are multiple ways you can structure things.

You can use what's called the DOM to get the values out of the input tags.

```
<body>
  Name and age!
  <input type=text name=name id=name>
  <input type=number name=age id=age>
  <input type=submit onclick="myClientSideJavaScriptFunction()">
</body>

<script>
  function myClientSideJavaScriptFunction() {
    var inputOneValue = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var inputTwoValue = document.getElementById('age').value;

    google.script.run
     .addProduct(inputOneValue, inputTwoValue);
  };
</script>
```

### Code.gs

```
function addProduct(x1, anythingYouWantToNameIt) {
  var myArray = [];
  myArray.push(x1);
  myArray.push(anythingYouWantToNameIt);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(myArray);
};
```

Comment: thank you, let me see how this works and i share my comments later

Comment: I found this method [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039519/add-basic-data-to-a-google-spreadsheet-via-a-simple-html-form/34474613?noredirect=1#comment56691122_34474613 , but when I send the data the variables sends first the text input, then the number input, and i want that the variables send in orden. In the form I have 50 cuestions more or less, but not all the variables will be stored, thats why I need id all the variables and store in orden.

Comment: You'll need to use `console.log()` in the browser, and `Logger.log('my var: ' + variableName);` in the `.gs` code to debug what the problem is.  And check the Execution Transcript and the browsers console log for error messages.