# Send only some variables to spreadsheets from an html form

Tags: html, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I found this method for store data from an html  [link][Add basic data to a Google Spreadsheet via a simple HTML Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039519/add-basic-data-to-a-google-spreadsheet-via-a-simple-html-form/34474613?noredirect=1#comment56691122_34474613) , but this method send the data not in order. I want to send data in order and only some variables
I have this html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form" method="get" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzhVAFaP7tFTbSzgeO0y9rUBl6ptVRCbqpS9wi12yFmoboYjw/exec" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    Name and age!
    <input type=text name=name id=name>
    <input type="text" name="direccion" placeholder="Direccion completa">
    <input type=number name=age id=age>
    <input type="Apellido" name="Apellido" id="Apellido">
    <input type=submit onclick=google.script.run.addProduct()>
</form>      
</body>
</html>
```

And I have this code.gs in my spreadsheet

```
function doGet(e){
  var vals=[];
  vals.push(new Date());
  for(var i in e.parameter){
    vals.push(e.parameter[i]);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KYR7SefLy5P-JP3LqdKsRRd_bkwTHFGFQQ0rnD3JfUM").appendRow(vals);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Información enviada correctamente");
}
```

There is some way to send the variables in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a form is submitted from an action in the form tag, the form element is submitted to the URL.  The form element is an object.  An object will change the order of the elements.  An array guarantees the order of the data, an object does not guarantee the order of the data in the object.

However, you can refer to each element in the object by it's key name, which in this case will be the name attribute.

```
function doGet(e){

  var vals=[];
  vals.push(new Date());
  vals.push(e.parameter.name);
  vals.push(e.parameter.direccion);
  vals.push(e.parameter.age);
  vals.push(e.parameter.Apellido);

  Logger.log('vals: ' + vals);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("").appendRow(vals);
  //return ContentService.createTextOutput("");
};
```

The only way to guarantee the order, is to set the order before the data is sent, or set the order after the data is retrieved.  The above example sets the order when the data is processed.

And the only way to send some input values is to process the form before it's sent.  Obviously, you can omit some of the values on the server side.  If you are going to use the strategy with the action in the form tag, then you don't need the:

```
onclick=google.script.run.addProduct()
```

in the Submit button.