# How to correctly write into Google Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a webpage with a form and I have to send data to a Google Spreadsheet. [I found a good code searching this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039519/add-basic-data-to-a-google-spreadsheet-via-a-simple-html-form?answertab=votes#tab-top) but I don't know how to edit it to store my data in Google Spreadsheet.

My form is made this way

```
<form name="reqForm" id="reqForm" method="get" action="SCRIPT" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="reqID" id="reqID" />
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
               <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"/>
            <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
               <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"/>
            <label for="SERIAL">Serial:</label>
               <input type="text" name="serial" id="serial"/>
            <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
               <input type="text" name="email" id="mail"/>
            <label for="text">Request:</label>
               <textarea id="text"></textarea>
               <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

The script is the same, from the example I linked (I just changed the function name because of an error)

```
function doPost(e){

   var id = "";
   var name = e.parameter['name'];
   var surname = e.parameter['surname'];
   var serial = e.parameter['serial'];
   var eMail = e.parameter['email'];
   var text = e.parameter['text'];
   var date = new Date();
   var ans = ""
   var flag = "WIP";

   var vals = [id, date, name, surname, serial, eMail, text, ans, flag];

  var sheetObj = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myKey").getSheetByName('Requests').appendRow(vals);
  // return ContentService.createTextOutput(e);
```

}

If I fill the form in this way:

- Name: John
- Surname: Doe
- Serial: 123456
- Email: 123@456.com
- Request: Hello

in my Spreadsheet I see data in this order: 
`[DATE] [Serial] [Mail] [Name] [Surname]`

How can modify the function to put my data into the spreadsheet in some kind of order that I can decide?

**[UPDATE]**: I updated the code: the result of this is a line correctly ordered but filled with "undefined"...

Comment: The method in the form tag is GET: `method="get"`  The function name in your Apps Script file is `doPost()`  That won't work.  You either need to make a POST request, or use `doGet()`  So, . . . GET for `doGet()`  and POST for `doPost()`  They need to match.

Comment: Yes I figured it out but when I try with method="post" I got an error, it says it cannot find function doPost. That's why I wrote "I had to change because of an error"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After submitting the form, you can get form parameters using `e.parameter[<parameter_name>]`.

For example to get the surname,

```
var surname = e.parameter['surname'];
```

To insert form data in Google Spreadsheet,

```
var sheetObj = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myKey").getSheetByName("sheetname");
//Here you can shuffle the order of values anyway you want.
sheetObj.appendRow([DATE, Serial, Mail, Name, Surname]);
//or you can do it like this
sheetObj.appendRow([DATE, Mail, Name, Surname, Serial]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! I tried this way but it seems the function cannot identify the parameters. I followed your advice but now it only gives me the date because I generate it in my code, the other values are disappeared 

Comment: Did you deploy the script as a web app with a newer version? If you haven't the script will execute the older version of the code

Comment: Yes but it seems not working at all (I changed the output to check and it's still the same...) I'll try creating a brand new script...

Comment: If possible share a dummy script with us

Comment: Ok I created a new project and the filling is working except for the fact I now see my line full of "undefined" ‍♂️

Comment: I'll do as soon as I can

Comment: All is good in your code, except you forgot to use the `getSheetByName("sheetname")` method before using `appendRow()` method

Comment: Your parameter names do not match in HTML and script do not match.

Comment: I'm sorry I was translating the script and I missed something... In my code everything matches, that's why I cannot understand why it's not working... I'm calling parameters by their IDs but it doesn't work...

Comment: GOT IT! I was missing the names and now it works! THANKS A LOT!