# Web page button to pass value to excel spreadsheet displayed on another page

Tags: html, excel, spreadsheet

is there a way to add several simple buttons to a web page that when pressed by a user, adds a fixed value to cell in a spreadsheet viewable on another page,on the same site, without viewing that other page. I would also like that to be the only way to add any data to that spreadsheet.

I Have been asked for more information. so i have included the code i have so far, which works fine however i would like to change where the change is outputted to. 
I would like the word "Press" to be in a cell on a spreadsheet on another page on the same site and for that word to change to the word "Pressed" when the button is pressed.

```
<body>

       <!-Changing the text->
<button id=" Button1 ">Press Me</button>
    <div id=" firstTxt1 ">Press</div>


<script>
// Changing text script
document.getElementById(" Button1 ").onclick = function (){
    document.getElementById(" firstTxt1 ").innerHTML = "Pressed";

}

</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Yes, there's a way. May you include a portion of you code please and detail what you've tried?

Comment: Hi there, I have not started the project yet as i could not find a way to do it without including a complete spreadsheet to a page, I do not want the user to see the spread sheet, however i would like to view and edit the data myself and even point a spreadsheet at the page to collect the data. A place to start is all i am looking for, im not asking anyone to complete the project for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a web Page html only solution is not the normal way. Generally, a web app would be used instead to communicate events between different views - something like a dotnet core web app.

In your case it seems you have 3 elements:

1. "data entering" html web page,
2. spreadsheet,
3. "data" viewing html web page.

How you interface with the spread sheet depends on the type of spreadsheet you are using, and where it is located.
if it is a google sheet, this answer might help
[spread sheet button with java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039519/add-basic-data-to-a-google-spreadsheet-via-a-simple-html-form).

The question lacks a lot of detail, and is very general, but I hope this helps you get started